# How to draw a bezier curve with variable thickness on an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, bezier

I want to make a visualization with bezier curves connecting boxes. More important edges should be thicker. Every box has one output but many inputs. Therefore, I want to keep the thickness of the incomit edges constant (to save space) and alter only the thickness of the outgoing edges (of which there is only one per box).

This is why I want to draw bezier cureves with different thickness at each end. They shall be rendered on an HTML canvas element. I know `context.bezierCurveTo()` but that only allows one thickness of the curve.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. (Unless you create your own JS graphic library which will support this)

Comment: I am not certain, but in the tutorial in the deleted question, can't you do this part "context.lineWidth = 10;" and have it use that thickness?

Comment: If it's not possible, can I maybe reuse existing functionality? Say get the pixels for two bezier curves and manually plot them and fill the space in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose that you are drawing a curve, that is thick 2 times `r` at x1,y1 and controll-point 1 is in x-driection then you can do something like:

```
  canvas.fillStyle = "red";  

  canvas.beginPath();  
  canvas.moveTo(x1, y1-r);  
  canvas.bezierCurveTo(cpx1, cpy1, cpx2, cpy2, x2, y2);
  canvas.bezierCurveTo(cpx2, cpy2, cpx1, cpy1, x1, y1+r);
  canvas.lineTo(x1, y1+r);  
  canvas.fill();
```

Comment: Of course, you can fill the shape... *facepalm* Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody else wants to do something similar, here's my code:

```
function plotFlow(context, centerLeft, centerRight, thicknessLeft, thicknessRight) {
    var leftUpper = {x: centerLeft.x, y: centerLeft.y - thicknessLeft / 2};
    var leftLower = {x: centerLeft.x, y: leftUpper.y + thicknessLeft};
    var rightUpper = {x: centerRight.x, y: centerRight.y - thicknessRight / 2};
    var rightLower = {x: centerRight.x, y: rightUpper.y + thicknessRight};

    var center = (centerRight.x + centerLeft.x) / 2;
    var cp1Upper = {x: center, y: leftUpper.y};
    var cp2Upper = {x: center, y: rightUpper.y};
    var cp1Lower = {x: center, y: rightLower.y};
    var cp2Lower = {x: center, y: leftLower.y};

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(leftUpper.x, leftUpper.y);
    context.bezierCurveTo(cp1Upper.x,cp1Upper.y, cp2Upper.x,cp2Upper.y, rightUpper.x,rightUpper.y);
    context.lineTo(rightLower.x, rightLower.y);
    context.bezierCurveTo(cp1Lower.x,cp1Lower.y, cp2Lower.x,cp2Lower.y, leftLower.x,leftLower.y);
    context.lineTo(leftUpper.x, leftUpper.y);
    context.fill();

    if (typeof context.endPath == 'function') {
        context.endPath();
    }
}
```